# One line ftp server in python

Tags: python, ftp, ftp-server

Is it possible to have a one line command in python to do a simple ftp server? I'd like to be able to do this as quick and temporary way to transfer files to a linux box without having to install a ftp server. Preferably a way using built in python libraries so there's nothing extra to install.

Comment: Unless you use an external python library like pftftpdlib, I doubt you can do this with one line of code.  Python has a built in ftp client, but not a server.

Comment: transfer files to linux??? why don't you just use scp?

Comment: Why not use **sshfs**? For fastest transfer rates (in a LAN) use option `-o Ciphers=arcfour`, i.e. `sshfs $REMOTEHOST:$DIRECTORY $MOUNTPOINT -o Ciphers=arcfour` and copy, move, rename, manage your files in your filesystem. sshfs is also available for Mac OSX.

Comment: related language agnostic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Obligatory [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) example:

```
twistd -n ftp
```

And probably useful:

```
twistd ftp --help

Usage: twistd [options] ftp [options].
WARNING: This FTP server is probably INSECURE do not use it.
Options:
  -p, --port=           set the port number [default: 2121]
  -r, --root=           define the root of the ftp-site. [default:
                    /usr/local/ftp]
  --userAnonymous=  Name of the anonymous user. [default: anonymous]
  --password-file=  username:password-style credentials database
  --version         
  --help            Display this help and exit.
```

Comment: Very nice! But the OP asked to use the standard python library because he didn't want to install other libraries.

Comment: Right, I do deserve down-voting, but really, people should know Twisted. And of course Twisted is in the base install of many Linuxes.

Comment: I didn't down-vote because it's a nice answer, ever if a bit O, and people from the future will find it useful when they search for similar problems.

Comment: I tried that, accessing from the web timeouts, accessing with telnet asks for a USER and a PASSWORD.

Comment: @AliAfshar Does this work on Windows too? I tried to install twisted using the Anaconda distribution but [haven't had any luck](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30903001/2766558).

Comment: @MichaelA Should certainly work on windows.

p.s. It's weird visiting my own future.

Comment: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ for those, like me, who had not heard of Twisted. I will edit the question to add the link (only; no further change)

Comment: On most platforms twisted install is as easy as `pip install -U twisted` which is not directly mentioned on the linked site.

Comment: OP asked for a one-liner, so can you please this one line using twist? I'm serious - I tried to use twist (python3), but I was not able to find the right arguments such that a) I am able to upload somthing and b) not my entire home gets exposed via ftp.

Comment: FYI, I tried twistd ftp, but were unable to upload file (permission error, cannot understand why). `pyftpdlib` worked as expected from the first shot.

Comment: This does not actually work for uploads. Even with passing `--root` and using the `memory` auth string, `strace` shows that it tries to walk the home directory. No joy.

Answer (score 126):

Check out [pyftpdlib](https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib) from Giampaolo Rodola.  It is one of the very best ftp servers out there for python.  It's used in google's chromium (their browser) and bazaar (a version control system).  It is the most complete implementation on Python for [RFC-959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) (aka: FTP server implementation spec).

To install:

```
pip3 install pyftpdlib
```

From the commandline:

```
python3 -m pyftpdlib
```

Alternatively 'my_server.py':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pyftpdlib import servers
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
address = ("0.0.0.0", 21)  # listen on every IP on my machine on port 21
server = servers.FTPServer(address, FTPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

There's more examples on the website if you want something more complicated.

To get a list of command line options:

```
python3 -m pyftpdlib --help
```

Note, if you want to override or use a standard ftp port, you'll need admin privileges (e.g. sudo).

Comment: As of 1.3.0: `>>> from pyftpdlib import ftpserver`: `pyftpdlib\ftpserver.py:54: DeprecationWarning: pyftpdlib.ftpserver module is deprecated`

Comment: Updated Wed Aug 27, 2014 for current version.  Shouldn't have deprecation warnings, now.

Comment: is this secure?

Comment: @TechJS pyftpdlib supports ftp over TLS (RFC 4217).

Comment: @BrianBruggeman No by secure I mean not exposing ftp over internet, not doing anything unintended and not stealing my data, I mean is the source code secure enough to be used in production environments?

Comment: Unfortunately pyftpdlib is not a builtin in Python 3 anymore, leaving us without a replacement

Comment: pyftpdlib was never a builtin.  You would need to use pip3 to install: `pip3 install pyftpdlib`.

Comment: even in terminal it shows it is successfully connected, in filezilla I got connection refused error. I couldn't fix it even though I used with anonymous user and user with password

Answer (score 49):

Why don't you instead use a one-line **HTTP** server?

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

will serve the contents of the current working directory over HTTP on port 8000.

If you use Python 3, you should instead write

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

See the [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) module docs for 2.x and the [http.server](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/http.server.html) docs for 3.x.

By the way, in both cases the port parameter is optional.

Comment: I don't think this allows him to upload files.

Comment: No resume, single connection, etc.

Comment: @RomanPlášil it will, just run server on another end xD   simply as it is

Comment: The question is about setting up a FTP server, not HTTP.

Comment: Works for mac if you want to download a file from mac.

Answer (score 34):

The answers above were all assuming your Python distribution would have some third-party libraries in order to achieve the "one liner python ftpd" goal, but that is not the case of what @zio was asking. Also, SimpleHTTPServer involves web broswer for downloading files, it's not quick enough.

Python can't do ftpd by itself, but you can use **netcat**, `nc`:

`nc` is basically a built-in tool from any UNIX-like systems (even embedded systems), so it's perfect for "**quick and temporary way to transfer files**".

Step 1, on the receiver side, run:

```
nc -l 12345 | tar -xf -
```

this will listen on port 12345, waiting for data.

Step 2, on the sender side:

```
tar -cf - ALL_FILES_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND ... | nc $RECEIVER_IP 12345
```

You can also put `pv` in the middle to monitor the progress of transferring:

```
tar -cf - ALL_FILES_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND ...| pv | nc $RECEIVER_IP 12345
```

After the transferring is finished, both sides of `nc` will quit automatically,  and job done.

Comment: Speaking of assuming... You assume that the clients are going to be unix machines with `tar` and `nc` available. What if it's windows?

Comment: wow this is convenient. Would there be any GUI wrapper build around this? I wouldn't be able to pitch command line way to my folks, a simple UI would make it happen

Comment: @jlh You can use it via Cygwin on Windows, it seems. Cygwin's not a tiny install, but if you need to do much Linux-like stuff on the command-line in Windows, it should be convenient and easy.

Answer (score 24):

For pyftpdlib users. I found this on the pyftpdlib website. This creates anonymous ftp with write access to your filesystem so please use with due care. More features are available under the hood for better security so just go look:

```
sudo pip3 install pyftpdlib

python3 -m pyftpdlib -w  

## updated for python3 Feb14:2020
```

Might be helpful for those that tried using the deprecated method above.

*sudo python -m pyftpdlib.ftpserver*

Comment: You can skip `sudo` if you install in a venv

Comment: don't forget that there's the v3 variant: `pip3 install pyftpdlib` and `python3 -m pyftpdlib -w`. worked like a charm for me.

Comment: thanks! This works beautifully for quick transfer between computers at home.

Comment: this one works nicely for me, is there a sftp server in one line?

Answer (score 6):

```
apt-get install python3-pip

pip3 install pyftpdlib

python3 -m pyftpdlib -p 21 -w --user=username --password=password

-w = write permission

-p = desired port

--user = give your username

--password = give your password
```

Comment: @karel They cover the same library, but they do not look like duplicates to me.

Answer (score 4):

Install:

```
pip install twisted
```

Then the code:

```
from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory, FTPRealm
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess, FilePasswordDB
from twisted.internet import reactor

reactor.listenTCP(21, FTPFactory(Portal(FTPRealm('./'), [AllowAnonymousAccess()])))
reactor.run()
```

Get deeper:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/

Answer (score 4):

The simpler solution will be to user pyftpd library. This library allows you to spin Python FTP server in one line. It doesn’t come installed by default though, but we can install it using simple apt command

```
apt-get install python-pyftpdlib
```

now from the directory you want to serve just run the pythod module

```
python -m pyftpdlib -p 21
```

Comment: Looks good, but what kind of authentication does happen? I get "530 Authentication failed."

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about a one-line FTP server, but if you do

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

It'll run an HTTP server on 0.0.0.0:8000, serving files out of the current directory. If you're looking for a way to quickly get files off a linux box with a web browser, you cant beat it.