# One Line FTP Server

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

A lot of times I used the command, which opens a temporary HTTP server on current directory:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Now I need to receive files, is there any one-line command that opens a ftp server?

I am simply looking for a command line ftp server, no configurations files, no daemons.

I tried Twisted as in [One line ftp server in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994638/one-line-ftp-server-in-python) , but the user has no permission to send files...

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little bit? Are you simply looking for a command line ftp server or something else?

Comment: I am simply looking for a command line ftp server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are looking for a Python solution, check out [pyftpdlib](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/).

You can install it using e.g. pip:

```
pip install pyftpdlib
```

then run it like this:

```
python -m pyftpdlib
```

This runs the anonymous-writable FTP server at localhost, port 2121 by default, serving files from the current directory (i.e. from wherever you started it). To login, use **anonymous** as both username and password.

Obviously, this is very insecure, so you would have to take that into account - if you want anything more then a toy or something to work with in development etc., use a proper FTP server as others mentioned.

Comment: To start the server with write access run `python -m pyftpdlib -w`. See FAQ at https://pythonhosted.org/pyftpdlib/faqs.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) ([`ftp-srv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv) module)

`npx ftp-srv ftp://0.0.0.0:2121 --root .`

This starts an FTP server listening on TCP port 2121 on all interfaces, which uses the current directory as the root (this is actually the default, so the `--root .` could be omitted for this particular case) and accepts all logins.
([`npx`](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner) downloads the module and runs its main script with the options provided.)

You may also want to check out the `--pasv_url` option to enable passive mode.

For more details, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv#cli

```
Options:
  --help             Show help                                         [boolean]
  --version          Show version number                               [boolean]
  --credentials, -c  Load user & pass from json file                    [string]
  --username         Blank for anonymous                  [string] [default: ""]
  --password         Password for given username                        [string]
  --root, -r         Default root directory for users                   [string]
  --read-only        Disable write actions such as upload, delete, etc
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  --pasv_url         URL to provide for passive connections             [string]
  --pasv_min         Starting point to use when creating passive connections
                                                        [number] [default: 1024]
  --pasv_max         Ending port to use when creating passive connections
                                                       [number] [default: 65535]
```

Answer (score 0):

One common command line ftp server is [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html). This is also the default ftp server on Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora, NimbleX and RHEL Linux.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use `vsftpd` as a one-liner? In my experience it's configured with a (potentially quite complex) configuration file and run as a system service/daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **twistd**:

```
$ virtualenv try-twisted
$ . try-twisted/bin/activate
(try-twisted) $ pip install twisted[tls]
(try-twisted) $ twistd -n ftp --root=/my/share/dir --password-file=/tmp/pass.dat
```

and connect to ftp://127.0.0.1:2121 as anonymous

(to deactivate virtualenv run: `deactivate`)

---

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Answer (score -1):

Openssh has a SFTP server and the configuration is very easy.

FYI, plain FTP is more complex than HTTP. Take with care :)