# FTP server Client using ftplib

Tags: python, ftp-client, ftp-server

I am trying to implement both a FTP server and a client to transfer files, but i am basically unable to make a connection between the two using the `ftplib` module in python....

This is what I did, how can I fix the code?
Is there another approach?

Code for my server : -

```
       #making the important imports for file transfer :

       from ftplib import FTP

       ftp_object_server=FTP()
       #s = socket.socket()         
       host = "121.0.0.1"
       port = 1227
       ftp_object_server.connect(host,port)


       while True:
            c, addr = ftp_object_server.accept()
            print c
            print addr# Establish connection with client.
            print 'Got connection from', addr
            c.send('Thank you for connecting')

            ftp_object_server.close()                # Close the connection
```

Code for my client : -

```
     from ftplib import FTP


     ftp_object_client=FTP()

     host = "121.0.0.1" # Get local machine name
     port = 1227                # Reserve a port for your service.

     #---------Creating My Own Set of username and passwords ------------------------#
     Username=['abc','efg','hij']
     Password=['123']


     input_user_name=raw_input('Enter the Username')
     input_user_password=raw_input('Enter the password')           

     if input_user_name in Username and input_user_password  in Password:
         ftp_object_client.connect(host)
         print ftp_object_client.recv(1024)

         ftp_object_client.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib) module from the standard library only covers the client part of the FTP protocol.
So what you did is trying to open two connections to `121.0.0.1`. I'm assuming you meant `localhost`, which is `127.0.0.1` anyway.

Not knowing what you are actually trying to achieve, there are some options:

- transfer files using HTTP, use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (or `python3 -m http.server` in python3) and [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as client
- use a prexisting solution (see the answers to [One line ftp server in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994638/one-line-ftp-server-in-python))
- implement your own server

Comment: Better I will use the one line ftp server in python. And then use the FTPclient module.