# Python http server to download files from all locations on Windows PC

Tags: python

I have created a script to download files from my Windows PC by running "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000" from a specific directory.

This is my script:

```
import os, socket
myip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print "Open > " + myip + ":8000 < on your browser to access the File Server"
os.chdir("G:\\fileserver")
os.system("python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000")
```

The issue is that I want to include all files on my PC, but this will show only files inside G:\fileserver.

On Linux, I would have simply included "/", but I don't know what to include in Windows.

Comment: You have to do one for every partition, if you have separate drive letters.

Comment: You do not need os.system for this. You can import and run the SimpleHTTPServer module directly

Comment: See also [One line ftp server in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994638/one-line-ftp-server-in-python)

Comment: Did you find a way to run one server for all partitions on windows?