# Issue when uploading a file from client to server

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on a program that backs up files like OneDrive or iCloud.

I made everything work but when I send a file trough the sockets it just gets stuck until I close the connection.

Here is the code sample:

The client:

```
def UpdateFileOnServer(file):
    print("[!] Uploading file to server: ",file)
    with open(clientFolder+file,"rb") as f:
        s.sendall(file.encode())
        file = f.read()
        s.sendall(file)
    print("[!] File has been sent.")
```

The server:

```
with open(fileLocation,"wb") as f:
    print("[!] File recieved! Downloading...")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        if not data:f.close();break
        f.write(data)
```

So to summarize again:

- The client sends the file and says that it has been sent.
- The server receives about 90% of the file and indefinitely hangs until I CTRL+C the client
- When I do that the server finishes the file transfer and the file is successfully received.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: The file is 15kb

Comment: What is the size exactly?

Comment: Okay so I need to send the actual size of the file first, then receive the file until I hit the size mark then I break and wait for new ones. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine on my machine, with a 15KB randomly generated file.

Comment: It is still not working correctly on my machine. I will try to create separate files and run them to see if maybe I messed something about the integration.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off with [an ftp server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994638/2308683)

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try and will comment if it works out for me! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem thanks to all the kind commenters.

- Create a server socket.
- Connect with the client socket to the server socket.
- Send the file with the client to the server.
- When the client confirms that the file has been sent you close the connection.
- The server continues to listen for connections.
- Rinse and repeat!